# Are there any story based BDD test framework in python?

Tags: python, testing, bdd

I mean, we have rSpec, cucumber in the ruby world.
But do we have similar tools in python? How about robot framework? Can we use it as a story based BDD test tool?

I'm asking because I'm kind of buying the BDD, story based test stuffs.

Comment: aloe is a great tool - https://aloe.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python [freshen](https://github.com/rlisagor/freshen) is a python port of cucumber, implemented as nose plugin.

Answer (score 6):

Lettuce is another Python port of Cucumber. It works well and the documentation describes, among the usual usages, Django usage as well.

http://lettuce.it/index.html

And here's another blog post that describes BDD with Lettuce and Splinter:

http://cilliano.com/blog/2011/02/07/django-bdd-with-lettuce-and-splinter/

Comment: +1 thx for the lettuce links :D

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to take a look at [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/). 
It's built from the ground up to do BDD style testing as opposed to either an "add-on" to nose or a port from another framework.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the choices are lettuce, freshen and Robot Framework.

We use [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) because of many reasons few main ones are

1. It can do almost anything that other frameworks support + more
2. It has a nice IDE called RIDE
3. The reports that it generates are pretty extensive and also,
   flexible
4. It has a an active and growing user community

Answer (score 0):

My own experimentation led to [pyspecs](https://github.com/mdwhatcott/pyspecs/)--a minimalistic approach.  It's pretty easy to get working:

```
pip install pyspecs
```

And it's pretty easy to use too:

```
from pyspecs import spec, given, when, then, the


class simple_addition(spec):
    @given
    def two_numbers(self):
        self.first = 2
        self.second = 3

    @when
    def we_add_them(self):
        self.result = add(self.first, self.second)

    @then
    def the_sum_should_equal_5(self):
        the(self.result).should.equal(5)


def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

I would welcome and feedback/collaboration...